# Pylons. Call controller function from CLI

Tags: python, pylons, command-line-interface

As with the command line in Pylons call the REST function from controller such as update? How to pass a request.POST to update function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use paster's post command.  Below, I post to /login/attempt of a local app I've wrote.

```
$ paster post development.ini /login/attempt email_address=me password=invalid

## It returns this JSON
{"status": "fail", "value": "me is not a registered email address."}
```

Here is the docs for paster post -

> Usage: C:\cygwin\home\jaime\virtualenv\sstesting\Scripts\paster-script.py post [options] CONFIG
>   _FILE URL [OPTIONS/ARGUMENTS]
>   Run a request for the described application
>
> This command makes an artifical request to a web application that uses
>   a paste.deploy configuration file for the server and application.  Use
>   'paster request config.ini /url' to request /url.  Use 'paster post
>   config.ini /url < data' to do a POST with the given request body.  If
>   the URL is relative (doesn't begin with /) it is interpreted as
>   relative to /.command/.  The variable environ['paste.command_request']
>   will be set to True in the request, so your application can
>   distinguish these calls from normal requests.  Note that you can pass
>   options besides the options listed here; any unknown options will be
>   passed to the application in environ['QUERY_STRING'].
>
> Options:   -h, --help            show this help message and exit   -v,
>   --verbose   -q, --quiet   -n NAME, --app-name=NAME
>                           Load the named application (default main)   --config-var=NAME:VALUE
>                           Variable to make available in the config for %()s
>                           substitution (you can use this option multiple times)   --header=NAME:VALUE   Header to add to request (you can use
>   this option
>                           multiple times)   --display-headers     Display headers before the response body

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be to make a HTTP POST request directly:

```
$ curl -d 'arg1=value&arg2=another' http://host/path/controller/responds/to/
```